# sqlite3 update query refreshes electron renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, knex.js, node-sqlite3

I realized that when i use update query with knex (with sqlite3) in electron js, after query done, the renderer process refreshes automatically!
for example:

***index.html:***

```js
ipc.send('UpdateTheRow', {'Id': 1, 'Title': 'foo', 'Date': '01-01-2020'});
```

***main.js***

```js
    ipcMain.on('UpdateTheRow', (event, newData)=>{
        knex('Products').where({id: newData.Id}).update({
            title: newData.Title,
            enter_date: newData.Date
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
```

---

after running update request, console prints the Response , But ***the renderer refreshes!***

in other words when we do something like this:

***reaplce console.log in Main.js with:***

```js
indexPage.webContents.send("EditedTheRow", res);
```

and in
***index.html:***

```js
ipc.on('EditedTheRow', (event, response) => {
   alert('Updated');
}
```

the query works nice but ***we dont get any alert in Renderer***!

sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer:**

The main problem in my case was interference of several frame works!
I am using sqlite3, so the database saved as a file in my 'root' project folder. 
Along these i am using a "Hot Reload" frame-work that notices file changes.
And every time i use a query like Update, Insert, Delete that changes database, my db file changes and Hot reloader refreshes the Renderer process!

Comment: I have removed electrol-reload package and it's configuration but is page is reloading for each DB change. Any idea?